# TCP Server Java with PHP

Tags: java, php, tcp

JAVA CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
         ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(51);
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();
         System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
         PrintWriter out = 
                 new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         BufferedReader in = 
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
         if(in.readLine() == "xFF"){
             out.print("OK");
         }
         in.close();
         out.close();
         skt.close();
         srvr.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
      }
   }
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    $con = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 51, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    fwrite($con, "xFF");
    if(fread($con, 256) == "OK"){
        // Its Works
    }
?>
```

The PHP Code return: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(in.readLine() == "xFF")` => this will block forever since you do not send a newline character in your PHP script. Therefore you never send anything from your Java app and fread will never read anything at all. `fwrite($con, "xFF\n");` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right that you are trying to implement a "TCP-Server" with PHP. This is not possible is this kind you think:

Normally a PHP script will be terminated after 60 seconds. But you can override this behavoid is a .htaccess file, php.ini or with a php function.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 500
</IfModule>
```

**php.ini**

Look for the line with `max_execution_time` and increase the value.

**PHP**

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

However I would recommend not to implement a server in PHP. PHP scripts should simply deliver fast some data and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts is **exceeding** max execution  time of 60 seconds increase it to 300 or more seconds like this

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //max execution time set to 300 seconds
    $con = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 51, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    fwrite($con, "xFF");
    if(fread($con, 256) == "OK"){
        // Its Works
    }
?>
```